# Hadoop to Kafka Rest proxy

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka

I am curious to know how to make rest calls from Hadoop cluster to Confluent Kafka cluster using Rest Proxy?

Any architecture reference would be helpful.

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: I need to post data using Rest calls from Hadoop cluster to Kafka cluster using the Rest Proxy. I need to know how can i make rest calls using hadoop or i need some other layer for this purpose.

Comment: Right, but *what* is making the REST calls? And what are the calls? Are you trying to load data from HDFS into Kafka?

Comment: Yes from HDFS to Kafka

Comment: How did the data get into HDFS in the first place? Could it be written to Kafka from that process or system instead?

Comment: There are existing systems which send the data. I would like to know if we can use HBase REST API for pushing data to kafka with Confluent Rest proxy? I know this is not a standard use case but evaluating options.